# multiple is not a valid attribute of element fileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload

I am using 'multiple' attribute to choose and upload multiple files at the same time , but when I put the attribute multiple inside fileupload

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" multiple="multiple">
```

I see this message :

> Validation(ASP.net):Attribute 'multiple' is not a valid attribute of
>   element 'fileupload'

Any Ideas? I'm using .NetFramework 4.0

Answer (score 2):

What you need is:

```
AllowMultiple="true"
```

That will translate into html's `multiple="multiple"`

So define your `FileUpload` control in aspx as:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
```

Right now, you are getting the error because you are attempting to use HTML's *(multiple="multiple")* syntax in aspx.

Comment: Same message .. now
Attribute 'AllowMultiple' is not a valid attribute of element 'fileupload'

Comment: @JohnnyBravo, I am not sure why you are getting the error, just copy pase `<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />` in your aspx file and try running it.

Comment: I still got the same message

Comment: Where are you putting this code, is it an aspx file or html file ?

Comment: clean/rebuild your solution, try it in a new application, this should work. There seems to be some other issue with your application.

Comment: I put it in a new application , still got the same message

Comment: and you get the error on compiling the application ? is the fileupload control is defined inside form element ? could you modify your question with the code from your new application, the page should only have fileupload control in it.

Comment: <%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />

</asp:Content>

Answer (score 2):

.Net Framework 4.5 began support for the AllowMultiple attribute (`AllowMultiple=true`).  So you'll need to upgrade your .net version.

References https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.allowmultiple(v=vs.110).aspx